# Did Mark 5:2 put the author of Mark "in danger of eternal damnation"?

Tags: contradiction, mark, law

In **Mark 3:29-30** [KJV], we learn that calling someone's spirit "unclean" is unforgivable :

> [29] "But he that shall blaspheme against the Holy Ghost hath never forgiveness, but is in danger of eternal damnation." [30] "Because they said, He hath an unclean spirit."

Later in **Mark 5:2** [KJV], the author of Mark tells us :

> [2] "And when he was come out of the ship, immediately there met him out of the tombs a man with an unclean spirit,"

If Mark 3:29-30 is literal, **Did the author of Mark become "in danger of eternal damnation" by writing Legion's spirit was "unclean"?**

Comment: Jesus makes a general statement equating the two dispositions; blaspheming the Holy Spirit = having an unholy spirit. Eternally condemned only while being in this state.

Comment: The blasphemy against the Holy Spirit is to attribute the influence of the Divine Person of the  Holy Spirit (for example, as demonstrated in Jesus' miracles) to the influence of Diabolos. To rightly classify an unclean spirit (which influences a man in an obviously unclean manner) is proper classification, not blasphemy. I think this is a very simple matter, so comment, not answer, in this case is sufficient.

Comment: An unclean/unholy person would surely make unclean/unholy suggestions, so blaspheming the Holy Spirit who is clean and chaste . What the heart is full of the mouth speaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark 3:28-30 says this -

> **28** Truly I tell you, the sons of men will be forgiven all sins and blasphemies, as many as they utter. **29** But whoever blasphemes
> against the Holy Spirit will never be forgiven; he is guilty of
> eternal sin.”
>
> **30** Jesus made this statement because they were saying, “He has an unclean spirit.”

Notice that it is not Mark saying that someone has an unclean spirit but he is reporting that the accusing crown made such an accusation of Jesus.  Thus, it might be the accusing crown that is in danger of the unforgivable sin, not Mark, at least here.

In Mark 5:2, again, Mark writes under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit and thus is perfectly informed of the truth and so cannot be accused of the unforgivable sin.